# IE Distorts Slideshow "BACK" and "FORWARD" Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Live Example:
http://newsite.702wedding.com/vegas-wedding-chapels.asp

Works Great in FireFox, Chrome, but IE the Slide Show Arrow Buttons Move to the Left.

Any good PERMANENT fixes?
Or how can I address the IE users and give it extra left margin? (Seems Ugly, Any REAL fixs?)

Thanks Very Much,
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target Internet Explorer with conditional stylesheets to fix inconsistencies cause by IE. It's not ugly - it's a pretty common fix and if done carefully only requires a small number of styles specifically targeted at IE. Include your IE specific CSS files like so:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The top selector only targets IE7, while the bottom targets browsers <= IE6. You could also use `<!--[if lte IE 7]>` to target browsers <= IE7 with a single stylesheet instead.